# Jquery - Make div appear when selecting from Select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a small issue. On my registration form I have a few select menus, specifically for countries and their states.

For most countries, except for the US and Canada, there are no states.

So I have 2 divs. One for Country, which appears all the time, and one for States (US & Canada).

1. When the user selects a country other than the US or Canada everything is fine and the state div stays hidden.
2. However, when the user selects the US or Canada  I want their appropriate div to appear beneath.

Is there any way to do this?

```
<div class="dv_country">

        <select name="country" class="form-control"> 
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option> 
                <option value="United States">United States</option> 
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option> 
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option> 
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option> 
            </select>

</div>

<div class="dv_state_US">

            <select name="state" class="form-control"> 
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>    
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                </select>

    </div>

<div class="dv_state_CA">

            <select name="state" class="form-control"> 
                <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
                <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
                <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
                <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
            </select>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
.dv_state_US
{
   display:none;
}

.dv_state_CA
{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to link the relevant CSS and JavaScript code.

Comment: The only css is have right now is - display:none;

Comment: Post the JavaScript / jQuery.

Comment: yea, you kind of need Javascript / Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is nice and extendible - just add any more countries to the end, it'll happily deal with showing and hiding them at need.

It would be slightly nicer with an `id` or `class` on the country select element, but works the same regardless :-)

```
$("select[name=\"country\"]").on("change", function () {
    var country = $(this).val();
    $(".dv_state_US").toggle(country === "United States");
    $(".dv_state_CA").toggle(country === "Canada");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('select[name="country"]').on('change click', function () {
  var country = $(this).val();
  $('.autoState').css('display', 'none');
  if(country === 'United States') {
    $('.dv_state_US').css('display', 'block');
  } else if(country === 'Canada') {
    $('.dv_state_CA').css('display', 'block');
  }
});
```

```css
.autoState { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dv_country">
        <select name="country" class="form-control"> 
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option> 
                <option value="United States">United States</option> 
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option> 
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option> 
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>            
                <option value="Canada">Canada</option> 
        </select>
</div>

<div class="dv_state_US autoState">
            <select name="state" class="form-control"> 
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>    
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
            </select>
    </div>

<div class="dv_state_CA autoState">
            <select name="state" class="form-control"> 
                <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
                <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
                <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
                <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
            </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that simply with jQuery.
In the problem description you say Canada but i can't find Canada anywhere in the html so i used United Kingdom.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".country-select").change(function () {
        
        if($( ".country-select option:selected" ).text() == "United States")
            $(".dv_state_US").show();
        else
            $(".dv_state_US").hide();
        
        if($( ".country-select option:selected" ).text() == "United Kingdom")
            $(".dv_state_CA").show();
        else
            $(".dv_state_CA").hide();
        
    });

});
```

```css
.dv_state_US {
    display:none;
}
.dv_state_CA {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dv_country">
    <select name="country" class="form-control country-select">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
        <option value="United States">United States</option>
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="dv_state_US">
    <select name="state" class="form-control">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="dv_state_CA">
    <select name="state" class="form-control">
        <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
        <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
        <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
        <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() { // DOM Loaded event listener
  var dv_country = $("#country");
  
  var showDuration = 0;
  
  function display_states_US() {
     $(".dv_state_US").show(showDuration);
  }
  
  function display_states_CA() {
     $(".dv_state_CA").show(showDuration); 
  }
  
  function hide_all() {
     $(".dv_state_US").hide(0); 
     $(".dv_state_CA").hide(0);
  }
  
  hide_all();
  
  dv_country.change(function() {
    var country_selected = $(this).val();
    
    if (country_selected == "United States") {
      hide_all();
      display_states_US();
    }
    else if (country_selected == "United Kingdom") {
      hide_all();
      display_states_CA(); 
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dv_country">
  <select id="country" name="country" class="form-control"> 
    <option disabled="disabled" selected value="" selected="selected">-- Select Country</option> 
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option> 
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option> 
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option> 
  </select>
</div>

<div class="dv_state_US">
  <select name="state" class="form-control"> 
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>    
    <option value="CA">California</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="dv_state_CA">
  <select name="state" class="form-control"> 
    <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
    <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
    <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
    <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here is a simple example of how to do it with JQuery. You can modify the show duration with the variable `showDuration`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what JavaScript you already have in place, however you had jQuery tagged as well, so the following might be of use:

```
    $(function () {
        var class_map = {
            "United States" : 'dv_state_US',
            "Canada" : 'dv_state_CA',
        };

        $('.dv_country select').change (function () {
            var country = $(this).val ();
            for (var x in class_map) {
                var className = '.'+class_map[x];
                (x == country)
                    ? $(className).show ()
                    : $(className).hide ();
            }
        });
    });
```

Using an array to map the classes will make it easy to expand, however if you were to give the new drop downs a class predictable by the value of the original select it wouldn't be needed.